# Python 3.x: Print specific array items

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, try-except

I have **two nested arrays** which can look like this:

```
firstArray=[[1,10],[11,31],[32,40],[41,61],[62,78]]
secondArray=[[1,10],[12,32],[33,39],[41,78]]
```

I now want to **search the elements** of secondArray in firstArray. 
I want **two events** to be distinguished:

**1:** if the element is found directly, I want to print it.

**2:** If it is **not** found, I want to print the preceeding and following element, or the elements it spans/the elements that contain it.

**For example**, for second Array's [1,10] I want to print firstArray's[1,10], but for secondArray's [12,32] I want to print firstArrays's [11,31] and [32,40]. For secondArray's [33,39] I want to print firstArray's [32,40] and so on.

I know, that I can access the two arrays with a nested for loop and that I can access the elements via indexing. I am having trouble to do the part, if there are no direct hits.

for the **direct hits**, I am doing the following:

```
foundYou=[]
for entry in firstArray:
    for element in secondArray:
        if(entry[0] == element[0]) and (entry[1] == element[1]):
            foundYou.append(element)
```

I also did some research about indexing, but could not figure out, how to solve this. I also thought of using <=, >=, < and >, but it would then print all elements with a smaller number than the search at first position, but it would ofc print a lot more than I want.

I could "index" using a map and another array with values from 1...length of array, but that seems to be a rather complicated way to achieve what I want.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: currently working on the following idea: store current position of element (=index) in a variable to use it to print previous and following elements (e.g.) by accessing firstArray[variable.-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, I am printing the value and it's corresponding result.

```
firstArray=[[1,10],[11,31],[32,40],[41,61],[62,78]]
secondArray=[[1,10],[12,32],[33,39],[41,78]]

foundYou=[]
for second in secondArray:
    for firstindex,first in enumerate(firstArray):
        if second == first:
            foundYou.append(first)
            print(second,":",first)
        else:
            if second[0] >= first[0] and second[1] <= first[1]:
                foundYou.append(first)
                print(second,":",first)
            else:
                try:
                    if second[0] >= first[0] and second[1] <= firstArray[firstindex+1][1] and second[0] < first[1]:
                        foundYou.append(first)
                        foundYou.append(firstArray[firstindex+1])
                        print(second,":",first,firstArray[firstindex+1])
                except IndexError:
                    pass
```

Output:

```
[1, 10] : [1, 10]
[12, 32] : [11, 31] [32, 40]
[33, 39] : [32, 40]
[41, 78] : [41, 61] [62, 78]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
firstArray=[[1,10],[11,31],[32,40],[41,61],[62,78]]
secondArray=[[1,10],[12,32],[33,39],[41,78]]

foundYou=[]
didNotFindYou=[]
for element in secondArray:
      if element in firstArray:
         foundYou.append(element)
      else:
         index = firstArray[secondArray.index(element)]
         nextindex = firstArray[secondArray.index(element)+1]
         didNotFindYou.append([index, nextindex])
print('found:', foundYou)
print('did not find:', didNotFindYou)
```

Output:

```
found: [[1, 10]]
did not find: [[[11, 31], [32, 40]], [[32, 40], [41, 61]], [[41, 61], [62, 78]]]
```

I iterate trough the `secondArray` only because you said you want to check if items in `secondArray` are in `firstArray`, this is for line 6. And then i check if the element  is in `firstArray`, this is for line 7. And then i get the index of the element in `secondArray`, and then get the element with the same index in `firstArray`, this is in line 10. And then i did the same thing as mentioned in line 10 but just i add 1 to the index, this is for line 11.

if you need more help i will edit my answer and tell you the solution for what you asked for

Comment: currently trying, but I recieved a valueError, need to check my code

Comment: @Shushiro this worked fine for me, and by the way what's your error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
firstArray=[[1,10],[11,31],[32,40],[41,61],[62,78]]
secondArray=[[1,10],[12,32],[33,39],[41,78]]

for index2 in range(len(secondArray)):
    if secondArray[index2] == firstArray[index2]:
        print(secondArray[index2])
    else:
        try:
            print(firstArray[index2], firstArray[index2+1])
        except IndexError as e:
            print(e)
```

Output:

```
 [1, 10]
 [11, 31] [32, 40]
 [32, 40] [41, 61]
 [41, 61] [62, 78]
```

Explanation:

Here we need to check the elements of secondArray with firstArray. So iterate over the second array

```
for index2 in range(len(secondArray)):
```

Using `if` check whether the element in second array is equal to first array at the respective position

```
if secondArray[index2] == firstArray[index2]:
```

If condition satisfies print the value otherwise it has to print the element and next element from first array

```
print(firstArray[index2], firstArray[index2+1])
```

Comment: @Shushiro: It is tested. and let me know Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: yes, I think that is it! since I also recieved some non fitting answers, was my formulation of the question bad? how can I phrase it better for the future?

Comment: actually, It is very close. in the thrid line for example, I do not want the output [41,61]. The searched pair [33,39] is fully covered with [32,40]. But its a minor problem, you helped me a lot already

Answer (score 1):

I have the following:

```
firstArray=[[1,10],[11,31],[32,40],[41,61],[62,78]]
secondArray=[[1,10],[12,32],[33,39],[41,78]]

for s2, e2 in secondArray:
  foundYou = []
  for entry in firstArray:
    s1, e1 = entry
    if s1 <= s2 and e1 >= e2:
      foundYou.append(entry) # We are fully contained within one entry
    elif s1 <= s2 and e1 <= e2 and s2 <= e1:
      foundYou.append(entry) # The start is within this entry but the end is in another
    elif s1 >= s2 and e1 >= e2 and s1 <= e2:
      foundYou.append(entry) # The end is within this entry but the start is in another
    elif s1 >= s2 and e1 <= e2:
      foundYou.append(entry) # This entry is entirely enveloped

  print(foundYou)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 10]]
[[11, 31], [32, 40]]
[[32, 40]]
[[41, 61], [62, 78]]
```

If anyone fancies minimising this please do!